# Need help getting Registry.GetValue to work correctly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, setup-deployment

I have a simple setup project that is no longer working and it seems like a windows update is the cause.  I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7.  The project is 64bit.  It still works on some computers but it does not work on any computers that have had updates recently.

Here is the original code:

```
    Dim appPath As String = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Our Company Inc.\SoftwareName.exe", "Path", "Not Found")

    appPath &= "Colorbar.col"

    Dim sid : sid = "S-1-1-0"
    Dim objWMI : objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://./root\cimv2")
    Dim objSID : objSID = objWMI.Get("Win32_SID='" & sid & "'")

    Dim userAccount As String = objSID.AccountName
    Dim fileInfo As IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(appPath)
    Dim fileAcl As New FileSecurity

    fileAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(userAccount, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))

    fileInfo.SetAccessControl(fileAcl)
```

I have put the key value pair of "Path" and "[TARGETDIR]" in the registry editor and have the output from this installer class (the code above) in the Install and Commit custom actions.

This code that used to work now returns "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation -> C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\Colorbar.col"

I have checked the registry when this message appears and the path is correct so I don't know where SYSWOW64 is coming from.

I have tried to change getting the appPath using this code:

```
  Dim regKey As RegistryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64)
    regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Our Company Inc.\SoftwareName.exe")
    Dim appPath As String = regKey.GetValue("Path").ToString
```

This returns an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

I have made a test Windows Form application and put both versions of code in a button event.  Everything works as expected.  Any ideas why the code does not work in a setup project anymore and what I can do to get it working again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally have it working again. I got around using the registry by using the custom action's CustomActionData and setting it to:

/name="[TARGETDIR]\"

I was then able to access it in my installer class by using this line of code:

Dim appPath As String = Context.Parameters.Item("name")

Once the path was set, everything else worked as expected.  The final code looks like this:

```
Public Overrides Sub Commit(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)
    MyBase.Commit(stateSaver)
    Dim appPath As String = Context.Parameters.Item("name")
    appPath = appPath.Remove(appPath.Length - 1)
    appPath &= "Colorbar.col"

    Dim sid : sid = "S-1-1-0"
    Dim objWMI : objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://./root\cimv2")
    Dim objSID : objSID = objWMI.Get("Win32_SID='" & sid & "'")

    Dim userAccount As String = objSID.AccountName
    Dim fileInfo As IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(appPath)
    Dim fileAcl As New FileSecurity

    fileAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(userAccount, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))

    fileInfo.SetAccessControl(fileAcl)
End Sub
```